# Cannot use aggregate on a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which I filtered in this way:

```
var items = myList.Select(c => c.foo == 1)
                  .Aggregate((decimal s, decimal c) => s.prop + a.prop);
```

the compiler say:

> Select does not contains a definition for Aggregate

what I did wrong??

Comment: `.Select(c => c.foo == 1)` returns an `IEnumerable<bool>`. Did you mean `.Where(c => c.foo == 1).Select(c => c.foo)` instead?

Comment: @Caramiriel if I use your code I lost the definition and I can t acess to property `decimal does not contain a definition for prop`

Comment: You might want to use `myList.Where(c => c.foo == 1).Aggregate(0m, (decimal c, SomeData x) => x.prop + c)`, but I'm not entirely sure on what you're trying to do. Could you add to the question what the input is, and what you're expecting to get?

Comment: @Caramiriel I need to sum of the value of the list that match with 1, if I use only `Where` I get `list does not contain a definition for aggregate` which is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to sum of the value of the list that match with 1, if I use only Where I get list does not contain a definition for aggregate which is my question.

[Here is an approach](https://dotnetfiddle.net/thJGDi) that works with `Aggregate`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myList = new List<SomeObj>() { new SomeObj(1, 10), new SomeObj(1, 20) };

        var sum = myList
             // filter for values of foo that equal 1
            .Where(c => c.foo == 1)
             // accumulate those values 
            .Aggregate(0m, (decimal acc, SomeObj next) => acc += next.prop);

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}

public class SomeObj
{
    public int foo { get; set; } = 1;
    public int prop { get; set; } = 10;

    public SomeObj(int foo, int prop)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.prop = prop;
    }

}
```

Comment: But what about just using `Sum(c => c.prop)`?

Comment: @Nkosi For this case, `Sum` would work too. The question was about `Aggregate`, and the original poster might have different, additional requirements in mind that `Sum` cannot handle.